# Adding a custom OnMarkerDragListener makes markers no longer draggable

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps v2 in an Android application that I'm writing. After creating the map and adding all the markers to it, I make all the markers draggable by using `marker.setDraggable(true);` for each marker on the map.

If I run the code like this, the markers are indeed draggable. However, I'd like to change the icon or color of the marker while it's being dragged, so I set up an OnMarkerDragListener, like so:

```
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
        }
    });
```

After adding in that block of code, though, the markers are no longer draggable. The color successfully changes in both the onMarkerDragStart and onMarkerDragEnd methods, but that's it. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here, and why the markers aren't getting dragged ?

Comment: have you tried adding the listener, but withoout changing the icon? i would say that the problem comes from changing the icon rather than from settings the listener.

Comment: @CarlosRobles That worked. Why does changing the icon of the marker affect the dragging? And is there a way to do what I want to do? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

i would say that the problem comes from changing the icon rather than from settings the listener.

Please note that Marker.setIcon is not a function that is available in all the versions of the   GoogleMaps V2 API. This means that probably it is not available in the library you have, or in the version of the play services installed in the device in which you are trying your app, and that could be causing any kind of malfunction.

As you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#may_2013) that function was added in May 2013. Please try updating everything, the google-play-services_lib, and the play services installed in the device.

If this happen to fix it, then you can try to change the icon only depending on the version installed on the mobile.

Comment: On my phone, I have Google Play Services 4.1.32. On my computer/in the Android SDK, I've got 4.0.30. The icon changes like I want it to (so I'm guessing my versions are new enough, since the `marker.setIcon` calls work), the marker just won't move after the icon has been changed.